# Elasticsearch Mapping Inconsistency error during read from ES Index using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to read bulk data from Elastic Index using a Spark job. During the read the process is failing with the following error,

```
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalStateException: Position for 'xxxx.yyyy' not found in row; typically this is caused by a mapping inconsistency at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.RowValueReader$class.addToBuffer
```

I guess the issue was due to that the document present in index doesn't have the field that is present in the mapping.

Say, the field `xxx.yyy` is present in mapping, but not all the documents stored in that particular ES Index have the field `xxx.yyy`.

Is there a property that I can set in my spark configuration to bypass this issue?.

```
    val spark = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .appName("ESToMongoDataUpload")
        .config("es.nodes", Config.ES_NODES)
        .config("es.net.http.auth.user", Config.ES_NET_HTTP_AUTH_USER)
        .config("es.net.http.auth.pass", Config.ES_NET_HTTP_AUTH_PASS)
        .config("es.net.ssl", Config.ES_NET_SSL)
        .config("es.nodes.wan.only", Config.ES_NODES_WAN_ONLY)
        .config("es.read.field.as.array.include", esConfig)
        .config("es.read.metadata", true)
        .config("spark.es.mapping.date.rich", false)
        .getOrCreate()


    import spark.implicits._

    val df = spark.read
        .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
        .option("query", esQuery)
        .option("pushdown", "true")
        .option("scroll.size", 10000)
        .load(Config.ES_RESOURCE)
        .withColumn("_id", $"_metadata".getItem("_id"))
        .drop("_metadata")
```

Is there a way I could bypass the mapping inconsistency error?. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I had to patch Spark ES adapter for this. I will contact Spark ES guys to see if they want to include my patch.

Comment: @DoruChiulan, Do you have any update on this?. We are stuck with this issue for a long time and I see no fix from ES. Could you help us?

Comment: Unfortunately as I worked on a separate branch than master (6.3.2), I didn't have time to adapt the changes to master in order to create a Pull Request. I'll try to have a look on Monday to see if it's complicated or easy to port my work.